# ggarrange the x axis of the bottom graph is cut off

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been using ggarrange to produce ggplots ready for publication. However I have a problem when I place a few graphs together the x axis of the bottom one gets cut off. Anyone knows why this happens and how I can fix this?
my data is-

```
woodland_percent <- c(90.09123,27.8298,23.82899,71.55523,19.13882,54.23152,70.10015,32.22501,74.50687,69.31365,64.02374,87.90138,14.94234,56.39798,81.16609,71.49775,88.05792,78.91833,87.62558,52.25957)
first_last <- c(first,first,first,first,first,first,first,first,first,first,last,last,last,last,last,last,last,last,last,last)
```

and my code:

```
 woodhist0.5full <- ggplot(shift_0.5full, aes(x = woodland_percent, fill = first_last)) +      geom_histogram(position = "dodge", alpha = 1, bins = 10)+geom_vline(xintercept=30,linetype="dashed", color="red", size=2)+  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey60", "black")) +theme_bw() +  labs(fill = "") +theme(panel.grid = element_blank())

figure_0.5full <- ggarrange(woodhist0.5full,woodhist0.5full, woodhist0.5full,woodhist0.5full  + rremove("x.text"), 
      labels = c("A", "B", "C"),
      ncol = 2, nrow = 2)

annotate_figure(figure_0.5full,
            top = text_grob("0.5 full ", color = "red", face = "bold", size = 14),
            bottom = text_grob("", color = "blue",
                               hjust = 1, x = 1, face = "italic", size = 10),
            left = text_grob("", color = "green", rot = 90),
            right = "",
            fig.lab = "Figure 1", fig.lab.face = "bold")
```

This is the result I get: if I put 4 graphs, the bottom right gets cut off and if I put 3 graphs the bottom left. This also happens if I arrange them one on top of the other in three rows and also if I place them one next to the other in one row with three columns.

[image]

[image]

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this happens because you added `rremove("x.text")` to the last plot?

Comment: YES! I deleted that and it resolved the issue! Thank you!